# Splitting equations and tags within an align environment

Tags: align, split

I'm trying to split an equation over two lines, and split a comment over two lines as well, using the split environment.

```
\begin{align} 
\begin{split}
f(x) =& f(y) + g(y) & \text{Something happening here}\\
    &+ A_n + B_n &\text{something else happening here}
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

I'm getting errors telling me I can't use `&` characters within the split environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `aligned` or `alignedat` if you want more control on the space between the two blocks.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
f(x) &=f(y) + g(y)      &\qquad& \text{Something happening here} \\
     &\quad + A_n + B_n &      & \text{something else happening here}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It seems the best way to do this is to have two splits:

```
\begin{align} 
\begin{split}
f(x) =~& f(y) + g(y) \\
    &+ A_n + B_n 
\end{split}
\begin{split}
& \text{Something happening here} \\
& \text{something else happening here}
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

Comment: `=&` will give bad spacing, you probably want `&=` (or `={}&` )

Comment: This generates errors due to the `$`  and missing `\end{split}` please post a small error free document